# How to Manipulate dictionary data in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested-lists

I have a dictionary with:

```
mydict = [
           {"product_id": '1', "qty": 2,'req_id':'1'},
           {"product_id": '1', "qty": 3,'req_id':'2'},
           {"product_id": '2', "qty": 4,'req_id':'3'},
           {"product_id": '2', "qty": 5,'req_id':'5'},
           {"product_id": '2', "qty": 5,'req_id':'6'},
           {"product_id": '3', "qty": 5,'req_id':'7'},
         ]
```

And I want to convert it by  common product_id. It will sum qty and show the req_id into nested dict. Expected result:

```
[
  {"product_id": '1', "qty": 5, reqId:[{'req_id':'1','req_id':'2'}]},
  {"product_id": '2', "qty": 14, reqId:[{'req_id':'3','req_id':'5','req_id':'6'}]},
  {"product_id": '3', "qty": 5, reqId:[{'req_id':'7'}]},
]
```

I have tried so far:

```
  ids = {}
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(mydict)):
        if list(mydict[i].values())[0]:
            if ids == {}:
                ids[list(mydict[i].values())[0]] = list(mydict[i].values())[1]
            elif list(mydict[i].values())[0] in ids:
                ids[list(mydict[i].values())[0]] = ids[list(mydict[i].values())[0]] + list(mydict[i].values())[1]
            elif list(mydict[i].values())[0] not in ids:
                ids[list(mydict[i].values())[0]] = list(mydict[i].values())[1]

   
    new_ids = []
    new_qts = []

    for i in ids.keys():
        new_ids.append({"product_id": i})
    for j in ids.values():
        new_qts.append({"qty": j})

    for i in range(len(new_ids)):
        new_ids[i].update(new_qts[i])
```

And I get this result

```
[
{"product_id": '1', "qty": 5},
{"product_id": '2', "qty": 14},
{"product_id": '3', "qty": 5},
]
```

Now I want to get the req_id in that dict.

Any help regarding this would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Also post what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have updated the question with what I did so far.

Comment: I've just realised you can't have a `dict` like this: `{'req_id':'1','req_id':'2'}` You have duplicate keys. One will overwrite the other.

Comment: Ok, I got the solution, thanks